# How to determine programatically an IP6 parent

Tags: php, ipv6

So with PHP and IP4 we can convert the IP address to IPLong and then compare it to a range by calculating an IP ranges start and end point and matching inbetween. Great.

My question though is how do we tackle this with IP6? Take this address for example:
`2600:1f18:16b:bc00:486e:75af:fd29:cabe`

The internet registrys release a list of IP6 ranges and these include (but are not limited to:)

- `2600::`
- `2600:8::`
- `2600:140::`

And possibly applicable to our example IP:

- `2600:1f00::`

But how can I calculate this or confirm it in a simple way? How can I determine which parent range an IP6 address belongs to?

An example of the source data (from ARIN) is:

```
arin||ipv6|2604:7382::|31||reserved|
arin||ipv6|2604:7384::|30||reserved|
arin||ipv6|2604:7388::|29||reserved|
arin||ipv6|2604:7390::|28||available|
arin||ipv6|2604:73a0::|27||available|
```

Comment: Ranges always include a prefix length, written as 2600:1f00::/x, where `x` is the length. You don't include those in your question, so it becomes impossible to answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with example data from ARIN

Comment: It works the same way for IPv6 as it does for IPv4, except the IPv6 address is 128 bits instead of 32 bits. Mask off the address with the network mask (address `AND` mask) and compare to the network. If they are equal, then the address is part of the network.